# Preprocessor macro and BOOL weirdness

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

Code below yields the output "yes defined", "no defined" and "yes". Why?

```
#define FOOBAR NO
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef YES
    NSLog(@"yes defined");
#endif

#ifdef NO
    NSLog(@"no defined");
#endif

#if FOOBAR == YES
    NSLog(@"yes");
#else
    NSLog(@"no");
#endif
    // ...
}
```

YES and NO are not undefined, objc.h defines them as:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL;
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the value of `NO`? If it's undefined (like `YES`), they will both [evaluate to 0](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If).

This means your expression is essentially

```
#if 0 == 0
```

which is of course true, and thus causes the first call to be compiled.

UPDATE: Not sure how `BOOL` is defined, but casting to what might be a `typedef`:ed type is not a very good idea when dealing with the preprocessor. Remember that the the `#if` is evaluated by the preprocessor, not by the compiler. Read something like [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If) for more information about expressions in the preprocessor. Especially:

> The preprocessor does not know anything about types in the language.

Comment: but why YES is equal to 0? it is 1

Comment: The point that the preprocessor doesn't understand types seems to me to be the answer. The preprocessor can compare `0` with `1`, but not `(BOOL)0` with `(BOOL)1`.

Answer (score 4):

All identifieres that the preprocessor doesn't know of are replaced with `0` for evaluation in `#if` directives. If you don't have defined `YES` and `NO` both are `0` (and thus equal).